# Running a windows batch file from Jenkins installed on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on a Linux server. It takes a built war file and deploys it to another linux machine and restarts tomcat.

What I want to do after that is run a batch file on a windows machine that runs some Postman tests against that install. I'm not sure how to accomplish this as nobody else in the office has ever done this.

Is this possible without something like Wine?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to add that Windows machine as an "agent" node. It wouldn't have a full Jenkins installation. Here's [some documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows) on adding a Windows agent (formerly referred to as slave nodes). You can then have that agent run the batch script, or whatever you need.